# Is strategy pattern helpful for this scenario?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have two classes A & B and both class implements the interface ISomeInterface. But some properties are not required for both class A & B. 
But in the client app I am calling the same ISomeInterface to invoke both the classes. The problem which I have is I don't want `Dictionary<string, string>` & TypedDataSet, `IList<Record>` properties in the same interface. But the clients needs to use this IsomeInterface.

Actually DataValues() property is only applicable to class A. 
Similarly MetaData() and RecordCollection() properties are applicable to class B. 
Also, if I introduce a new class C in future and that needs a separate property like this then my code will look ugly which I don't want. 
So, Is there any way I can still use the same IsomeInterface in my client app and have the appropriate properties in the corresponding classes? 
I think I need to use Strategy Design pattern but got confused on how to implement the same. correct me if I am wrong?

See below:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
 string Id{get; set;}
 void Display();
 Dictionary<string, string> DataValues{get;};
 TypedDataSet MetaData{get; }
 IList<Record> RecordCollection{get; }
}

public class A: ISomeInterface
{
public string Id 
{
        return "A1";
}

void Display()
{   
    Console.Writeline("class A");
}

public Dictionary<string, string> DataValues()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, string>();
}


public TypedDataSet MetaData()
{
    //I dont want this method for class A
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public IList<Record> RecordCollection()
{
    //I dont want this method for class A
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}


public class B: ISomeInterface
{
public string Id 
{
        return "B1";
}

void Display()
{   
    Console.Writeline("class B");
}

public Dictionary<string, string> DataValues()
{
    //I dont want this method for class B
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public TypedDataSet MetaData()
{
    return new TypedDataSet();
}

public IList<Record> RecordCollection()
{
    IList<Record> rc = null;

    //do something
    return rc;
}
 }
```

Client App -

```
Main()
{
ISomeInterface a = new A();
a.Display();
Dictionary<string, string> data = a.DataValues();

ISomeInterface b = new B();
b.Display();
TypedDataSet data = b.MetaData();
IList<Record> rc = b.RecordCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strategy does not really work for you in this case.

We must question why you must call ISomeInterface when its implementing classes do not support all methods. It is probably best to have several inheriting interfaces.

- ISomeInterface

  - IClassAInterface
  - IClassBInterface

Then, pick which Interface is most appropriate for usage.

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
   string Id{get; set;}
   void Display();
}
interface IClassAInterface
{
   Dictionary<string, string> DataValues{get;};
}
interface IClassBInterface
{
   TypedDataSet MetaData{get; }
   IList<Record> RecordCollection{get; }
}
```

The example usage you given isn't really helpful - you already know which class you are instantiating (new A() and new B()) so the interfaces aren't going to give you any added abstraction. So let us think of an example where this technique is more useful:

```
public class SomeCollection
{
   public ICollection<T> retrieveItems<T>() where T : ISomeInterface
   {
       //... retrieve relevant instances.
   }
}
```

Then

```
var col = new SomeCollection();
// Populate... 
var someInterfaces = col.retrieveItems<ISomeInterface>();
foreach(ISomeInterface instance in someInterfaces){
   instance.Display();
}

var classAInterfaces = col.retrieveItems<IClassAInterface>();
// etc.
```

---

So I guess in the end, if you're trying to get a bunch of "RecordCollection" from a collection of As and Bs, you really need to rethink your design.

Comment: The interface example you have provided is exactly what I want but how I will access the ISomeInterface commonly in my client app for class A & B?

Comment: You can keep ISomeInterface as per normal, but you are limited to using ISomeInterface methods (Id() and Display()). Is that not enough?

Comment: Then how I can set my data values to the properties?

Comment: Can you provide example of a property that needs to be set, and how it is mapped to each datasheet type?

Comment: Class A needs DataValues property to be set. It is just a Dictionary<string, string>. Class B needs Metadata & RecordCollection properties to be set. The Metadata will have a Key & value combination and the RecordCollection is a collection of Record object which is nothing but age, gender, name & value.

Comment: Are the abstracted properties the same? For example, does both DataSheets have Age,Gender,Name.

Comment: 75 datasheets contains only data-element-id and a value (I mean lot of data-elements). But the other 10 datasheets contains multiple records of Age,Gender,Name and value.

Comment: If they're completely different things, with no common properties, then there's no way you can access those properties through a common interface. You can cast from IDataSheet to IDataSheetTypeA, and IDataSheetTypeB, after you have figured out what type of DataSheet they are.

Comment: But I have few things in common like Id, IsDataSheetValid, HasAnyErrors, ApplyCheck, DisplaySheetName() & etc... the only problem which I face was with the Data Values.

Comment: So put those common things in IDataSheet. If you need to do anything that is relevant ONLY to DataSheetA, cast to IDataSheetA. "IDataSheetA dataSheetA = (IDataSheetA)someReferenceToDataSheet; dataSheetA.DataValues["key"] = ["value"]; "

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your thought. Definitely I will try this and let you know the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A principle of software design that applies here is that classes should not be forced to implement methods of interfaces that they will not use.  So the interface should only have methods and properties on it that all classes that implement the interface will use.

Other than that I think it depends a lot on what you are trying to model in your domain and your existing application, etc, as to what sort of solution you choose.  i.e. more specific information is needed to give further advice.

Comment: Hi eaglestorm, thanks for your reply. Actually we have been using class A in our app for the past 5 years and just now we got another scenario where we need to use class B and that's why we want to stick to the same interface as our entire app refers to the same.

Comment: @user972255 bite the bullet. Refactor the design. Else the app will just be walking on crutches forever. Easy way - rename all references of ISomeInterface to IClassAInterface. Then recreate ISomeInterface, and create IClassBInterface. Put common interface methods in ISomeInterface.

Comment: @DarylTeo: Can you tell me how to handle this If I need to refactor?

Comment: @user972255 see my answer. I had to make some assumptions based on the information given, so let me know if there is anything inaccurate. Some actual sample code of how you are using ClassA, and ISomeInterface would be helpful

Comment: @DarylTeo: Let me explain the actual scenario. In our app, we are storing two different xml data formats in the db. one xml format has been referred by 75 data sheets and the other xml format has been referred by 10 data sheets. So, we will be loading the xml's in the domain object and accessing everywhere using the IDataSheet interface. And we don't want to have another interface as the maintenance in future will be very hard.

Comment: @user972255 Right, and in your code, when you use IDataSheet, how do you differentiate when to call 1 method, and when to call the other method?

Comment: @DarylTeo: Based on the DB flag, we know which one to call and load the values. But again the problem is we don't want to carry unwanted properties for all the objects which doesn't need that.